# SELECT Products with only one word in their name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I select records from a table that have only one word.

For example the products table contains:

```
Alice Mutton
Aniseed Syrup
Boston Crab Meat
Camembert Pierrot
Carnarvon Tigers
Chai
Chang
Chartreuse verte
Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning
Chocolade
Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix
```

How do I get only these records:

```
Chai
Chang
Chocolade
```

Comment: Have you tried, [field] LIKE ('%Chai%') OR [field] LIKE ('%Chocolade%')?  (See answer for better explanation)

Comment: What is your definition of a word? Is it language sensitive?

Answer (score 4):

```
 Select [name] 
 From [table] 
 Where [name] Not Like '% %'
```

below will get any that have spaces in front or at the end. Although from experience you normally want to run an update with the trims to remove stuff like that:

```
 SELECT name,RTRIM(LTRIM(name)) From table
 WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(name)) NOT LIKE '% %'
```

Comment: Given equivalent alternatives, I prefer the version that uses ANSI SQL functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `CHARINDEX()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ',Products) = 0
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8abe7/2/0)

`CHARINDEX()` returns the position of a specific character within a string, it returns `0` if that character does not exist within the string.

Note, if your data has leading/trailing spaces you'd want to trim those:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(Products))) = 0
```

Comment: Might want to also trim to remove opening and trailing spaces. But you really want to look for all white space characters, not just a space.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this as an answer to add something more descriptive:

```
Select * from [table] where ([field] LIKE ('%Chai%') OR [field] LIKE ('%Chocolade%')) and NOT LIKE ('% %')
```

That will filter out any entries with a space as well.